# Powershell Select-String from a path name?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file with directory paths that I need to extract a few bits of info from to make a log file name. Not sure how to do this? 
   `Select-String` ?

CSV File looks like this

```
User,Computer,Directory
john.doe,CAD-12,C:\Cimatron\CimatronE11_64bit\Program\IT\var\post
john.doe,CAD-12,C:\Cimatron\CimatronE11_64bit\Program\IT\var\post2
john.doe,CAD-12,C:\Cimatron\CimatronE11_64bit\Data\templates
john.doe,CAD-12,C:\Program Files\CGTech\VERICUT 7.3.3\library
john.doe,CAD-12,C:\Program Files\CGTech\VERICUT 7.4\library
```

I know I have to import the CSV file, here is what I have.

```
$UsersCSV = import-csv C:\test.csv
foreach($Computer in $UsersCSV)
{$Logfile = Select-String "not sure how to search the string for what I want"
$LogFile
}
```

Need help with the `Select-String`. Here is what I would like to end up with or whatever is easiest that gives the `$Logfile` a unique name.

```
CimE11_post
CimE11_post2
CimE11_templates
VERI_7.3.3_lib
VERI_7.4_lib
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: "Whatever is easiest that gives the LogFile a unique name" is a counter going 1.log, 2.log, 3.log, 4.log ... n.log. Would that do? What you've described looks impossibly complicated - how would the script know that 'VERICUT' is important but 'CGTech' is not? And that 'VERICUT' makes sense if shortened to 'VERI', but 'templates' should not be shortened? What about if you just swap `\\ ` and `:` for `-` and get `C--Program Files-CGTech-VERICUT 7.4-library.log` ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler you are probably correct. I was just hoping to shorten the log names. I will probably go with this method and keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TessellatingHeckler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478656/tessellatingheckler) suggests a **pragmatic solution** in a comment on the question: replace `\` and `:` instances in the input path with a character that is legal in filenames to get a representation of each path that works as a *filename*:

```
Import-Csv C:\test.csv | % {  # % is a built-in alias for ForEach-Object
  $Logfile = ($_.Directory -replace '[\\: ]+', '_') + '.log'
}
```

This yields the following filenames:

```
C_Cimatron_CimatronE11_64bit_Program_IT_var_post.log
C_Cimatron_CimatronE11_64bit_Program_IT_var_post2.log
C_Cimatron_CimatronE11_64bit_Data_templates.log
C_Program_Files_CGTech_VERICUT_7.3.3_library.log
C_Program_Files_CGTech_VERICUT_7.4_library.log
```

---

As stated in the comments, there is **no clear algorithmic logic behind the filenames you say you want**.

Here's a solution that produces the desired filenames, trying to remain as generic as possible.
This is probably not worth doing in real life, but perhaps it can inspire a real-life solution:

```
# Helper function that takes a directory path and converts it to a log filename
# representing that dir.
function pathToLogFilename([string] $path) {

  # Ordered hashtable defining regex-based transformations (replacements).
  # Entries are processed in order, and processing stops as soon as 
  # a match is found and the transformation has been performed.
  # Entry format: <regex> = <replacement>, to be passed to the -replace operator.
  $ohtTansform = [ordered] @{
    '^(.{3}).+?(E\d+).*$' = '$1$2' # 'CimatronE11_64bit' -> 'CimE11', for instance. 
    '^(.{4}).+? (\d.*)$' = '$1_$2' # 'VERICUT 7.3.3' -> 'VER_7.3.3', for instance
    '^(lib)rary$' = '$1'           # 'library' -> 'lib'
    '^(post.*|templates)$' = '$&'  #  preserve, if prefixed with 'post' or equal to 'templates' 
    '.+' = ''                      #  remove all other tokens
  }

  $logFilename = ''; $i = 0
  # Split the .Directory path into tokens (path components) and synthesize
  # the log filename from a subset of the tokens, with transformations applied.
  foreach($token in ($path -split '\\')) {
    # Apply transformation.
    $transformedToken = $token
    foreach($regex in $ohtTansform.Keys) {
      if ($token -match $regex) {
        $transformedToken = $token -replace $regex, $ohtTansform[$regex]
        break
      }
    }
    # Add transformed token to filename, separated with "_".
    if ($transformedToken) {
      $logFilename += $(if ($i++) { '_' } else { '' }) + $transformedToken 
    }
  }
  # Output the synthesized filename.
  $logFilename

}


Import-Csv C:\test.csv | % {
  # Call the helper function to transform the directory path to a log filename.
  $LogFile = pathToLogFilename $_.Directory
}
```

Answer (score -1):

-replace is your friend, below is an example of how I would get the strings you wanted out of the scenario you gave.

Hope this helps, and best of luck.

$file = import-csv $filename

foreach($dir in $file.directory){
if($dir -match "VERI"){
(((($dir).replace('C:\Program Files\CGTech\','')).replace('rary','')).replace('CUT ','*')).replace('\','*')
}

if($dir -match "Cima"){
(((($dir).replace('C:\Cimatron\','')).replace('atron','')).replace('*64bit\Data\','*')).replace('64bit\Program\IT\var\','')
}

}

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: A solution that is hard-coded to work only with the sample input is not helpful.